# So how do I set a Thymeleaf template resolver for my springboot webapp then

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I built a spring-boot webapp with a single home.html file under src/main/resources/template and when I return "home" from my spring controller it works perfectly. I'm packaging it as a war and it runs wonderfully with spring-boot's embedded tomcat server. If I run it with `mvn spring-boot:run`, that is.

But later if I start my application with `java -jar myjar.war` it claims the server has started up and all is well, but when I try to access it at localhost:8080 it fails with:

```
Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

So what do I have to do next then?

This is my pom.xml, by the way:

```
  <groupId>com.ciber</groupId>
  <artifactId>energyworx-conversion-tool</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>    
    <start-class>com.ciber.ewct.WebApp</start-class>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <!-- <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000</jvmArguments> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

After turning debug logging level on, I see this about thymeleaf configuration, which is the same for when I run it with `mvn spring-boot:run` and `java -jar`:

```
[THYMELEAF] * Cache Factory implementation: org.thymeleaf.cache.StandardCacheManager
[THYMELEAF] * Template modes:
[THYMELEAF]     * LEGACYHTML5
[THYMELEAF]     * XHTML
[THYMELEAF]     * HTML5
[THYMELEAF]     * VALIDXML
[THYMELEAF]     * VALIDXHTML
[THYMELEAF]     * XML
[THYMELEAF] * Template resolvers (in order):
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Message resolvers (in order):
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.spring4.messageresolver.SpringMessageResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect [1 of 2]: org.thymeleaf.spring4.dialect.SpringStandardDialect
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "th"
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect [2 of 2]: nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "layout"
[THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURED OK
```

Comment: How did you configured your Thymeleaf resolver ? Using spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf ?

Comment: I didn't configure it. I only added the the dependency to my pom:

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Try opening the packaged war file and checkout if templates/home.html is present into the archive.

You mentionned that you are packaging as a war file but I don't see any instruction in your pom concerning this packaging. By default, you should have a jar, not a war. Could it be you are trying to execute an old artifact ?

Comment: It's being packaged as a war, I've edited the question to include that part of the pom.xml.

Comment: I can see the war file in the target folder. It's not an old one. A new one gets generated when I run mvn clean package.

Comment: The home.html file is under WEB-INF/classes/templates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sad to say that you are actually doing it wrong.

You configured your build to exclude the webapp server from your package.

```
<packaking>war</packaging>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

With this setup, you have a war that can be deployed inside an existing Servlet container. You won't be able to start your app with a `java -jar` command.

If you want to run you webapp with a java command line. Replace your packaging to `jar` and remove the `provided` instruction from your pom.

```
<packaking>jar</packaging>
...
<!--
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
-->
```

Then you will have an embedded tomcat inside your jar and the command `java -jar myjar.jar` will properly.

Edit : Finally, I would raise the log level on Spring Web package to see how the Template Resolver tries to lookup your template.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: The documentation I read said that by packaging it like this, the tomcat jars would go into the folder lib-provided and make the war both deployable and able to run standalone.

Comment: I tried what you suggest but It still doesn't work though. I commented out the dependency and the war packaging. re-packaged it as jar. Still the same problem. And when I start the application, spring-boot claims everything has started up with no errors. It really only can't find the home.html for some reason.

Comment: Last thing to checkout, are you sure that `Error resolving template "home" ...` message is the root cause ? don't you have any exception before that ? When the view resolver encounters an error while executing the template, you'll get a stacktrace of the error, then Spring view resolver still tries to resolve the template, hence, failling.

Comment: Finally, I would raise the log level on Spring Web package to see how the Template Resolver tries to lookup your template.

Comment: I've edited the question to include thymeleaf configuration entries that I see after turning debug on.

Comment: And I don't see any exceptions before that one, no. That's the only one I get, which starts with:

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: Do you have any means to publish your code to a github repo ? At this point there is something missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106567/discussion-between-daniel-lavoie-and-henrique-ordine).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to revert everything so that it works as a standalone jar. I've added an answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it, with @DanielLavoie's help, by reverting all the changes I made to make the application a deployable war.

Those were:

- remove the `<packaking>war</packaging>` so that a jar is generated instead;
- remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from the dependency *spring-boot-starter-tomcat*;
- remove `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` from my `Application` class;

I don't like the solution because according to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) I followed you'd be able to make the war deployable and also standalone enabled. But it'll have to do for now.

Comment: Feels like you don't understand what it means to make a deployable war.

Making a deployable war means that you can only upload it to a servlet container. You cannot make a war both runnable and deployable.

Comment: Well then they shouldn't write that in their documentation.